# Why doesn't ellipse (\p and 1) work?

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


% DOES NOT WORK
%\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse (\p and 1);


%WORKS
\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse (1 and \p);

\end{document}
```

`(1 and \p)` works but `(\p and 1)` does not, why?

Comment: `\p{} and 1`, however, works.

Comment: @Andrey: If you make your comment as an answer, I will mark  it as the answer.

Comment: Welcome!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Spaces after TeX commands are ignored, thus by using `\p and 1` you'll get an equivalent of, say, `1and 1`, which you can verify to give the same error. Therefore we just need to restore the space:

```
\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse (\p{} and 1);
```

Note that, as Jake mentions, this syntax is deprecated (refer to the [TikZ manual](http://ctan.org/pkg/pgf)).

Comment: one typo detected.

Comment: @xport: you can also write `({\p}  and 1 )` but  I think `{\p}`and `\p{ }` are not fine , the better way is `x radius =`and `y radius=`

Answer (score 16):

The `(<x radius> and <y radius>)` syntax is old and, if not deprecated, at least not encouraged any more. The current way to do is is to use `[x radius]` and `[y radius]`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}


% WORKS with current syntax
\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse [x radius=\p, y radius=1];


%WORKS
\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse [x radius=1, y radius=\p];

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{tikz}    
\begin{document}    
\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse (\p cm and 1 cm);   
\tikz \foreach \p in {1,2,...,3} \draw (\p,0) ellipse (1 cm and \p cm);    
\end{document}
```

problem with the parser, I suppose ! and the remark of Jake is fine, better now it's to use `x radius` and `y radius`